# Laravel get multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build something like product variants, so far so good. But there is one problem.
I'm getting product and variables as separate json

Example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "panelgameid": 71,
        "name": "Counter-Strike 1.6",
        "active": 1,
        "minslots": 12,
        "maxslots": 32,
        "slotincreament": 2,
        "order": 1,
        "gameid": 1,
        "location": "Serbia",
        "price": 0.6
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "panelgameid": 71,
        "name": "Counter-Strike 1.6",
        "active": 1,
        "minslots": 12,
        "maxslots": 32,
        "slotincreament": 2,
        "order": 1,
        "gameid": 1,
        "location": "Germany",
        "price": 0.4
    }
]
```

And I have my games and my prices. But I want to show them like this.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "panelgameid": 71,
        "name": "Counter-Strike 1.6",
        "active": 1,
        "minslots": 12,
        "maxslots": 32,
        "slotincreament": 2,
        "order": 1,
        "gameid": 1,
        "prices": [
           {
           "location": "USA",
           "price": 0.6
           },
           "location": "Germany",
           "price": 0.4
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my current code as CONTROLLER:

```
$games = DB::table('games')
        ->join('prices', 'games.id', '=', 'prices.gameid')
        ->get();

        return $games;
```

Comment: Consider to use [Eloquent: One To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: And then error Method App\\Http\\Controllers\\GamesController::hasMany does not exist.

Comment: You have to crete the models and define the relationships. I will write an answer to show you

Comment: Thank you! I have very hard time with that. I'm expecting answer

Answer (score 3):

Create the Game and Price models by `make:model` artisan command:

```
php artisan make:model Game
php artisan make:model Price
```

You will find them at your project `/app` folder. There define the relationships.

**Game Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{

    // define the relationship with the Price model, one game has many prices
    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::class, 'gameid'); // you will have to make explicit the foreign key. Looking at the query in your question, I assume that it's gameid
    }

}
```

**Price Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Price extends Model
{

    // define the relationship to the Game model, one price belongs to a Game
    public function game()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Game::class, 'gameid'); 
    }

}
```

Then you can query the games with the prices in your **Controller**:

```
$games = Game::with('prices')->get();
```

You can read more about Eloquent ORM in the docs: [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent), and [Eloquent: One To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).